# EXC_BAD_ACESS at runtime during a pointer conversion

Tags: c, macos, lldb

I am trying to find the error here, the debugger stops at the following :

```
Pthread_create renderer passed

Renderer loop (re)started

Process 84779 stopped

* thread #4: tid = 0x3603, 0x0000000101546c4b libjess.so`render_deformation + 667 at renderer.c:472, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x36f0000)

    frame #0: 0x0000000101546c4b libjess.so`render_deformation + 667 at renderer.c:472

   469         for (i = 0; i < resy*resx; i++)

   470       {

   471         aux  =  (unsigned char *) ((*(tab1) << 2 ) + (unsigned int) buffer);

-> 472         *pix = *(aux) ;

   473         pix++;

   474         *pix = *(aux + 1);  
   475         pix++;
```

I suspect it has something to do with the pointer conversion. Can anybody tell me the best way to cast it.

Full code for the function (as requested):

```
void render_deformation(int defmode)
{
   unsigned int bmax, *tab1, *tab2, *tab3, *tab4, i;
   unsigned char *pix = pixel , *buf = buffer, *aux;


   SDL_LockSurface(screen);

   /**************** BUFFER DEFORMATION ****************/



   if (video == 8)
     {
       buf = buffer;
       tab1 = table1;
       tab2 = table2;
       tab3 = table3;
       tab4 = table4;
       bmax = resx * resy + (unsigned int) pixel;

       switch(defmode)
     {
     case 0:
       memcpy(pixel,buffer,resx * resy);
       break;
     case 1:
       for (pix = pixel; pix < (unsigned char *) bmax ; pix++)
         *pix = *(buffer + *(tab1++)) ;
       break;
     case 2:
       for (pix = pixel; pix < (unsigned char *) bmax; pix++)
         *pix = *(buffer + *(tab2++)) ;
       break;
     case 3:
       for (pix = pixel; pix < (unsigned char *) bmax; pix++)
         *pix = *(buffer + *(tab3++)) ;
       break;
     case 4:
       for (pix = pixel; pix < (unsigned char *) bmax; pix++)
         *pix = *(buffer + *(tab4++)) ;
       break;   
     default:
       printf("Problem with blur_mode\n");
     }
     }
   else
     {
       pix = pixel;

       bmax = resx * resy;
       switch(defmode)
     {
     case 0:
       memcpy(pixel, buffer, pitch * resy);
       goto nodef;
       break;
     case 1:
       tab1 = table1;
       break;
     case 2:
       tab1 = table2;
       break;
     case 3:
       tab1 = table3;
       break;
     case 4:
       tab1 = table4;
       break;

     default:
       printf("Problem with blur_mode\n");
     }
       for (i = 0; i < resy*resx; i++)
     {
       aux  =  (unsigned char *) ((*(tab1) << 2 ) + (unsigned int) buffer);
       *pix = *(aux) ;
       pix++;
       *pix = *(aux + 1);  
       pix++;
       *pix = *(aux + 2);  
       pix+=2;
       tab1++;
     }
       nodef:;

     }


   SDL_UnlockSurface(screen);
}
```

Comment: Wait, you're dereferencing `aux` which is an `unsigned char`?

Answer (score 3):

```
aux = (unsigned char ) (((tab1) << 2 ) + (unsigned int) buffer);
```

My guess is that that should have been:

```
aux = (unsigned char *) (((tab1) << 2 ) + (unsigned int) buffer);
```

255 is a very small value or range for a pointer...

But more code is needed, at least the whole function plus the relevant definitions/ declarations (what is "buffer" ?, why is it cast to unsigned int? ).

UPDATE 111206:

A similar thing seems to be the case with

```
bmax = resx * resy + (unsigned int) pixel;
```

Which should probably be:

```
bmax = resx * resy + (unsigned int*) pixel;
```

And:

```
aux  =  (unsigned char *) ((*(tab1) << 2 ) + (unsigned int) buffer);
```

Which should probably be

```
aux  =  (unsigned char) ((*(tab1) << 2 ) + (unsigned int*) buffer);
```

or:

```
aux  =  (unsigned char*) ((*(tab1) << 2 ) + (unsigned int) buffer);
```

This is all basic pointer arithmetic: it is either `pointer := pointer + scalar;` or `pointer = scalar + pointer;` , but `pointer := pointer + pointer;` makes no sense. The first variant is the most probable one (otherwise the casts would not be necessary).

Not sure about the types sizes, but they should at least be pointers.

There is still some wrong typing involved:

```
for (pix = pixel; pix < (unsigned char *) bmax ; pix++) {...}
```

Pixel and pix are char*; bmax is an unsigned int; the cast stinks. I'd expect something like:

```
for (pix = pixel; pix < pixel+bmax ; pix++) {...}
```

, and possibly the limit (bmax) should even be multiplied by 4 to make place for the 24+8 bit per cell  colorspace.

Comment: I have added the full code for the function. Hope it solves all your queries. 
Also I am getting following warning from the compiler.
'code renderer.c:471: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
renderer.c:471: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size.'
Line no 471 is   aux  =  (unsigned char *) ((*(tab1) << 2 ) + (unsigned int) buffer);

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind response. I do not think those lines are crashing the program. I have isolated the problem to  *pix = *(aux) ; (and other two similar lines such as (*pix = *(aux + 1); &  *pix = *(aux + 2); ) I am able to run fine when replacing aux with unsigned int, however It is not working properly :( .

I also wanted to add that this code is working fine on Linux Systems (as is). I dont know what Mac OS X is doing differently here.

Comment: I do think these lines cause trouble. Besides, they indicate that the person who wrote the code does not know C. The kind of errors looks like it has been typed over from a book, and corrections were made just until it compiled with warnings disabled (or ignored).

Comment: so what is your constructive comment in this ?

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that on lines 472 and 474 you store data to the memory address pointed to by pix from the address pointed to by aux, but your process does not have the ability to access one or both of those addresses. Make sure you correctly allocate that memory.